# Spark with custom Hadoop FileSystem

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I already have a cluster with Yarn, configured to use a custom Hadoop FileSystem in core-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.custom.impl</name>
    <value>package.of.custom.class.CustomFileSystem</value>
</property>
```

I want to run a Spark Job on this Yarn cluster, which reads an input RDD from this CustomFilesystem:

```
final JavaPairRDD<String, String> files = 
        sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("custom://path/to/directory");
```

Is there some way I can do this without re-configuring Spark? i.e. Can I point Spark to the existing core-site.xml, and what would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` to the directory that contains `core-site.xml`. (This is documented in [Running Spark on YARN](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html).)

You will still need to make sure `package.of.custom.class.CustomFileSystem` is on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen this!